# Comparing large exponents

Tags: exponentiation

Without calculator, I have to determine which of the following is larger:

$2^{350}$ or $5^{150}$

I know only very basic exponential laws, and haven't covered logarithms yet. Tried various algebraic simplification methods but had no luck.

Any help is much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Although this Question lacks context, it is six years old and at this point closing it would have no effect on improving site content. I voted to leave open.

Comment: Apart from the lack of context, the title is wrong since not the exponents have to be compared , but the powers. But it might be that the abstract context given was sufficient at this time.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**

This should help:

$$2^7=128>125=5^3$$

Answer (score 4):

To evaluate these values, they must be placed on the same “platform”.

Find $x$ such that $2^{350} = (x)^{50}$. Similarly, find $y$ such that  $5^{150} = (y)^{50}$.

These two numbers are now raised to the same platform and therefore can be  compared (now).

If $x > y$ then..., otherwise ......

Answer (score 1):

There is a simpler way which does not require the gcd or "common base" and works independent if the exponents share some bases:

If you have the two numbers:

$2^{350}$ and $5^{150}$

Choose the smaller of the two exponents, i.e. 150 and apply the reverse power to both sides, i.e.

${2^{350}}^{1/150}$ and ${5^{150}}^{1/150}$

This can be simplified to

$2^{350/150}$ and $5^1$

and further to

$2^{2.333...}$ and $5^1$

which makes the two sides easy to compare.

This way you can compare large numbers with huge exponents easily as you always get one of the two numbers to have exponent "1".

Note: You may need to compute non-integer exponents for the remaining power.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. How do you go from $\frac{350}{150}$ to $200$?

Comment: 2^(7/3)=128^(1/3) = ‘a bit more than 5’

Comment: Fixed the exponent computation, 350/150 => 2.333...

Answer (score 0):

The greatest common divisor between $350$ and $150$ is $50$ and we have

$350 = 7 \cdot 50$

and

$150 = 3 \cdot 50$

There's an exponent power rule that states $a^{x \cdot y} = (a^x)^y$

Thus you're comparing

$2^{7 \cdot 50}$ *or* $(2^7)^{50}$ *or* $128^{50}$

and

$5^{3 \cdot 50}$  *or* $(5^3)^{50}$ *or* $75^{50}$

Since $128 > 75$, then $128^{50} > 75^{50}$

Comment: I have downvoted your Answer because you only slightly elaborated on previous Answers (six years old at this point) without remarking on the duplication of ideas.

Comment: @hardmath I don't care much for votes. I came here looking for an explanation to a similar question. Both answers above look more like clues than explanations. The first never says why `50` and stops short of explaining how to get to the `x` and `y` that it alludes to. Whereas the second, which even titles itself as *Hint*, pulls a `3` and a `7` out of hat. I wrote an explanation from scratch with details that try to elucidate any mystery (e.g. GCD, exponent power rule). The fact that my answer shares digits with the previous ones is a property of math. Feel free to downvote.

Comment: If you edit your Answer so that it relates to the previous ones, I'll remove my downvote.